# Looping a date range sub + allocate days to their respective months

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

Would really appreciate some help on this

For the following dataset:

```
StartDate             EndDate               Days
0              2018-03-20 00:36:00       2018-05-01 00:42:00       42.004167
1              2018-05-01 00:42:00       2018-06-04 17:15:38       34.690023
2              2018-04-07 15:06:00       2018-05-09 17:01:00       32.079861
3              2018-03-21 04:36:00       2018-05-14 04:00:00       53.975000
4              2018-03-15 15:30:00       2018-05-08 08:30:00       53.708333
5              2018-05-08 08:30:00       2018-06-09 10:40:09       32.090382
6              2018-03-21 09:00:00       2018-05-16 13:40:00       56.194444
7              2018-03-31 06:00:00       2018-05-26 16:30:00       56.437500
8              2018-03-14 18:18:00       2018-04-27 01:00:00       43.279167
9              2018-04-07 15:00:00       2018-06-01 09:25:50       54.767940
10           2018-03-22 07:30:00       2018-05-20 19:00:00       59.479167
```

I was able to find the difference between the start and end dates and create the new column ‘Days’ like so:

```
df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate'])
df['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndDate'])
df['Days'] = df['EndDate'].sub(df['StartDate'], axis=0)
df['Days'] = df['Days'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
```

---

However I need to find this out:

For each row, **how many days were in each month and which particular month they were in**.

I think the best way would be to create columns for all possible months and attribute the days to their respective columns that way. But I come from an excel background and there’s probably a smarter way of doing it.

The reason being; to pay clients correctly according to the number of days worked between start date and end date, and to also attribute them costs on that basis. The full dataset is fairly large and so the script would have to handle a wide range of date variances in an efficient way.

### Thanks

black.mamba

Comment: Can you provide your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets try this one.

First create a series of days using `pd.date_range` with StartDate and EndDate for each records.  Next use, `dt` datetime accessor to get the month.  Use `value_counts` to count total months on each record.  Lastly, join the results to the original dataframe.  Plus, `import calendar` to get month name vs number, by using `rename` with a dictionary created from `calendar.month_names`.

```
import calendar
df.join(df.apply(lambda x: 
                 pd.Series(pd.date_range(x.StartDate,
                                         x.EndDate,
                                         freq='D')).dt.month,1)
          .apply(lambda x: 
                 x.value_counts(),1)
          .rename(columns=dict(enumerate(calendar.month_name))))
```

Output:

```
             StartDate             EndDate       Days  March  April   May  June
0  2018-03-20 00:36:00 2018-05-01 00:42:00  42.004167   12.0   30.0   1.0   NaN
1  2018-05-01 00:42:00 2018-06-04 17:15:38  34.690023    NaN    NaN  31.0   4.0
2  2018-04-07 15:06:00 2018-05-09 17:01:00  32.079861    NaN   24.0   9.0   NaN
3  2018-03-21 04:36:00 2018-05-14 04:00:00  53.975000   11.0   30.0  13.0   NaN
4  2018-03-15 15:30:00 2018-05-08 08:30:00  53.708333   17.0   30.0   7.0   NaN
5  2018-05-08 08:30:00 2018-06-09 10:40:09  32.090382    NaN    NaN  24.0   9.0
6  2018-03-21 09:00:00 2018-05-16 13:40:00  56.194444   11.0   30.0  16.0   NaN
7  2018-03-31 06:00:00 2018-05-26 16:30:00  56.437500    1.0   30.0  26.0   NaN
8  2018-03-14 18:18:00 2018-04-27 01:00:00  43.279167   18.0   26.0   NaN   NaN
9  2018-04-07 15:00:00 2018-06-01 09:25:50  54.767940    NaN   24.0  31.0   NaN
10 2018-03-22 07:30:00 2018-05-20 19:00:00  59.479167   10.0   30.0  20.0   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to filter this down to my requirement of showing month and year by changing dt.month to dt.strftime

```
df.join(df.apply(lambda x: 
             pd.Series(pd.date_range(x.StartDate,
                                     x.EndDate,
                                     freq='D')).dt.strftime('%b-%y'),1)

      .apply(lambda x: 
             x.value_counts(),1)
      .rename(columns=dict(enumerate(calendar.month_abbr))))
```

However the output now lists the columns in alphabetical order rather than Jan to Dec by order of year.

Any ideas on how to achieve this are welcome

#### Response by Scott Boston

First off, your above statement, you don't need the rename part because, you are already doing the renaming when you convert to %m from the date series.

Now, the problem occurs with this method when you take out the .dt.month which returns a "month number" that is used for sorting.  When you change that use month name, now you doing a lexicographical sort.  So, let's switch back to month number (for sorting) and do a little lambda function to convert columns from month number to name.

```
df.join(df.apply(lambda x: 
             pd.Series(pd.date_range(x.StartDate,
                                     x.EndDate,
                                     freq='D')).dt.strftime('%m-%y'),1)
     .apply(lambda x: 
               x.value_counts(),1)
     .rename(columns=lambda x: 
                     pd.to_datetime(x, format='%m-%y').strftime('%b-%y')))
```

Output:

```
             StartDate             EndDate       Days  Mar-18  Apr-18  May-18  Jun-18
0  2018-03-20 00:36:00 2018-05-01 00:42:00  42.004167    12.0    30.0     1.0     NaN
1  2018-05-01 00:42:00 2018-06-04 17:15:38  34.690023     NaN     NaN    31.0     4.0
2  2018-04-07 15:06:00 2018-05-09 17:01:00  32.079861     NaN    24.0     9.0     NaN
3  2018-03-21 04:36:00 2018-05-14 04:00:00  53.975000    11.0    30.0    13.0     NaN
4  2018-03-15 15:30:00 2018-05-08 08:30:00  53.708333    17.0    30.0     7.0     NaN
5  2018-05-08 08:30:00 2018-06-09 10:40:09  32.090382     NaN     NaN    24.0     9.0
6  2018-03-21 09:00:00 2018-05-16 13:40:00  56.194444    11.0    30.0    16.0     NaN
7  2018-03-31 06:00:00 2018-05-26 16:30:00  56.437500     1.0    30.0    26.0     NaN
8  2018-03-14 18:18:00 2018-04-27 01:00:00  43.279167    18.0    26.0     NaN     NaN
9  2018-04-07 15:00:00 2018-06-01 09:25:50  54.767940     NaN    24.0    31.0     NaN
10 2018-03-22 07:30:00 2018-05-20 19:00:00  59.479167    10.0    30.0    20.0     NaN
```